# ng change with custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Javascript code for directive

```
  angular.directive('uiDatePicker', [function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'EA',
                scope: {
                    ngModel: '=ngModel',
                    ngChange: '=ngChange'
                },
                templateUrl: 'complete/date-picker.tmp.html',
                replace: true,
                require: 'ngModel',
                link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
                    if(scope.ngModel !== undefined) {
                        scope.DatePicker = new DatePicker(new Date(scope.ngModel));
                    } else {
                        scope.DatePicker = new DatePicker();
                    }
                    scope.ngModel = scope.DatePicker.Value;
                }
            }
    }])
```

Javascript code for controller

```
    angular.controller('Main', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.Change = function(value) {
            console.log(value);
        };
        $scope.Value = 1000;
    }])
```

Html code

```
<div ng-controller="Main">
    <ui-date-picker ng-model="Date" ng-change="Change(Value)"></>
</div>
```

And my question: How to ng-change work ?. ngModel still work !

Comment: Can you show uiDatePicker Directive as well?

Comment: Your missing what kind of directive in your directive declaration. Try E for element.

Comment: @PSL, Okey, I was showed, Can you read and help me ?

Comment: And how does the template look like `date-picker.tmp.html` ? One thing is you would need to use `&` for function binding, not `=`

Comment: @PSL, Html code for template too long, Stackover flow not allow I post, What can I do ?

Comment: Can you prepare a plunkr?

Comment: Oh, my angular module seem complicate so need more times to prepare a plunk. If you know how to ngModel and ngChange can work in custom directive, Can you explain or show me your code ?